# How do I count multiple columns and mutiple distinct values in one column in a group by clause

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, count

I'm working on summarizing trailers by trailer length, door type, and lot location. Then counting the records grouped by length -by- door type -by- lot location, then stepping up one level and counting trailers grouped by length -by- door type. Lastly, counting total trailers by lot location.

I've tried this example;

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/23c89e/55

Also, I'm struggling to get the grouping and totals correct. This does correctly count trailers length -by- door type -by- lot location. However, I can't move the solution further.

This is the select statement that gets me this far.

```
SELECT g.length, g.doortype, g.location, g.total_location
FROM 
       ( SELECT length, doortype, location,  COUNT(*) AS total_location
         FROM trailers
         GROUP BY length, doortype, location
       ) AS g
```

Output example, this correctly counts by length, door type, and location but is not formatted and totaled correctly.

```
| length | doortype | location | total_location |
|--------|----------|----------|----------------|
|   28FT |  ROLL UP |    LOT C |              1 |
|   28FT |  ROLL UP |    LOT D |              2 |
|   28FT |    SWING |    LOT B |              1 |
|   45FT |  ROLL UP |    LOT B |              3 |
|   45FT |    SWING |    LOT B |              1 |
|   48FT |  ROLL UP |    LOT D |              1 |
|   48FT |  ROLL UP |    LOT E |              1 |
|   48FT |    SWING |    LOT A |              6 |
|   48FT |    SWING |    LOT B |              2 |
|   48FT |    SWING |    LOT C |              4 |
|   48FT |    SWING |    LOT E |              2 |
```

I'm trying to get the output to look like this.

```
| length | doortype | lot a | lot b | lot c | lot d | trailer total|
|--------|----------|-------|-------|-------|-------|--------------|
|   28FT |  ROLL UP |   1   |   0   |   1   |   0   |       2      |
|   28FT |  SWING   |   0   |   0   |   1   |   0   |       1      |
|   45FT |  ROLL UP |   1   |   5   |   0   |   0   |       6      |
|   45FT |  SWING   |   0   |   0   |   0   |   4   |       4      |
|   48FT |  ROLL UP |   2   |   1   |   0   |   1   |       4      |
|   48FT |  SWING   |   0   |   0   |   1   |   1   |       2      |
|------------------------------------------------------------------|
            TOTAL   |   4   |   6   |   3   |   6   |       19     |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## it will create few extra rows with doortype NULL , you can ignore that when you loop through

```
            SELECT tab.*
            FROM (SELECT 
                COALESCE(length, 'All length') AS length,
                doortype, 
                SUM(IF(location = 'LOT A', 1, 0)) Lot_A,
                SUM(IF(location = 'LOT B', 1, 0)) Lot_B,
                SUM(IF(location = 'LOT C', 1, 0)) Lot_C,
                SUM(IF(location = 'LOT D', 1, 0)) Lot_D,
                COUNT(case location when 'LOT E' then null ELSE 1 end) AS Trailer_Total    
            FROM trailers
            GROUP BY length, doortype WITH ROLLUP
            )tab
            where tab.doortype IS NOT NULL OR tab.length = 'All length'
            order by tab.length, tab.doortype
```

Comment: This also worked perfectly and it correctly totaled the lot locations. I'll study this select statement closely because you used some functions I haven't needed until now. Thank you for your help and time!

Answer (score 1):

Use Location as a filter and combine their count using sum.

```
SELECT 
    length, 
    doortype, 
    SUM(IF(location = 'LOT A', 1, 0)) Lot_A,
    SUM(IF(location = 'LOT B', 1, 0)) Lot_B,
    SUM(IF(location = 'LOT C', 1, 0)) Lot_C,
    SUM(IF(location = 'LOT D', 1, 0)) Lot_D,
    COUNT(0) AS Trailer_Total
FROM trailers
GROUP BY length, doortype;
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you for your time. I see how you did the select but don't understand the entire syntax of the select commands. I'll look those up in the mysql documentation this weekend. Thanks again for your time!